# how to get battery percentage back in status bar, Android 7.1.1

Tags: battery-life, notification-bar, 7.1-nougat

I have a Samsung Galaxy J2 Pro running Android 7.1.1, and Samsung Experience version 8.5.

How do I get the battery percentage into the status bar? I am sure it was there until yesterday (unless I am going crazy) and now it has disappeared. Yes I have tried turning it off and on :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found it myself when I had time to read through all the Settings in the manual:

1. tap "Settings"
2. tap "Display"
3. tap "Status Bar"
4. turn on "Show battery percentage"

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Tap on the Settings from the Home Screen.

Step 2: Select Smart manager

Step 3: Select Battery

Step 4: Now, you should see the option that can help you show the battery percentage.

Step 4: Turn Battery Percentage on.

Source:
https://phoneradar.com/samsung-galaxy-j2-pro-tips-tricks-faqs-options/#f

Comment: Thanks, but there is no Battery icon under Settings. Battery does appear under Settings -> Device Maintenance, but that has no "Show Battery Percentage" option.

Comment: Haha...funny how even the same android versions have different locations. Try the edited version. It should be in smart manager.

Comment: Thank you again, but I had no "Smart Manager" selection either. It was under "Display" then "Status Bar" (see my answer).